# List ExpandoObject properties at run-time by pressing "dot" in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamic, expandoobject, dynamicobject

In our .NET Core project we have service references for SOAP APIs. But since we have a lot of them, we implemented a generic method which invokes the method in SoapClient so that we can just call:

```
var response = await _service.CallMethod<ClientResponse>(request, "SaveClientAsync");
```

However, in this case we have to know the name of the method (here it's a "SaveClientAsync") while it's better to have something like client.SaveClientAsync so that I write "client", then press a "." and the list of properties shows in VS' dropdown menu allowing me to select the name of the method and pass it further.

First I thought about enum but I will have to support it which is not an option, but then I bumped into ExpandoObject so I can create a dynamic object having all the method names as properties.

What I need now is to expand the list of object's properties by pressing "." in Visual Studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd look for a code generator to create a SOAP client for you.

Comment: I do have a SOAP client, that was not a question actually. I want to pass the name of the method into the CallMethod method because it not just calls a SOAP client's method but also do some routine error handling which I don't want duplicate.